# Segment Event failing in Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

Given a video file, I am trying to play the video from a given start time to a given end time.
I am trying to achieve this using Segment Event as follows:

1. Firstly, I am creating and initialising a segment.
2. Created a segment event using gst_event_new_segment()
3. Send the segment event to the pipeline using gst_element_send_event()

But, The video just plays from the beginning and not from the start time.
The segment event does not have an effect on the playback eventhough the event is reaching the sink element of the pipeline (verified by gst debug messages).

Following is the code-snippet:

```
GstSegment *gstSegment;
GstEvent *event_seg;

gstSegment = gst_segment_new();
gst_segment_init( gstSegment, GST_FORMAT_BYTES );
gstSegment->rate  = 2.0;
gstSegment->start = 10 * 1920 * 1080 * 2;    
gstSegment->stop = 20 * 1920 * 1080 * 2;    

event_seg =  gst_event_new_segment(gstSegment);

ret = gst_element_set_state (data.videoPipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
    printf("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state\n");
    gst_object_unref (data.videoPipeline);
    return 1;
}

if ( !gst_element_send_event( GST_ELEMENT (data.videoPipeline), event_seg))
  printf("Error");
```

I am able to achieve this using Seek Event.
But unable to do with Segment Event.

Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this using Segment Event?

Comment: Not sure why you want to do it with the segment event if using the seek works just fine. Can you elaborate? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hello, did you solve you problem? I have almost the same.